# Declare class methods in __init__.py and put implementations in another file

Tags: python

I have a Python project with structure like this:

```
mypkg\
|- __init__.py
|- foo.py
```

In `foo.py` I have a class named Logger, with several methods in it with implementation:

```
class Logger:
    def log_info(self, content):
        print(f'[INFO] {content}')
    def log_error(self, content):
        print(f'[ERROR] {content}')
#...
```

`__init__.py` is blank. I want to put method declaration only and docstrings for SampleClass in this file for easy reading. How can I go about doing this? Thank you!

Comment: "I want to put method declaration only and docstrings for SampleClass in this file for easy reading" - you don't really want to do this. Whenever you re-write something in SampleClass, you'll need to remember to re-write `__init__.py` as well. No need to add this sort of coupling. Use an IDE that allows for fast code navigation instead.

Comment: Python doesn't have the concept of "declaration".

Comment: What exactly are you asking? If you want to put a stripped down clone of ``SampleClass`` into ``__init__.py``, you can just do so.

Comment: I assumed that was a typo and OP did not intend for the `Logger`/`SampleClass` inconsistency.

Answer (score 1):

You could set up `mypkg\__init__.py` thus:

```py
"""
mypkg
=====

A lovely duck that drinks milkshakes.
"""

from mypkg.foo import Logger
```

Then elsewhere:

```
>>> help(mypkg)

mypkg
=====

A lovely duck that drinks milkshakes.

>>> dir(mypkg)
[__lots__, __of__, __dunder__, __items__, __and__, Logger]

>>> from mypkg import Logger
>>>
```

`__init__.py` should have the full path to `foo`: `from mypkg.foo import Logger` rather than `from .foo import Logger`… there are good reasons for this but I don't remember what they are. <sub>Please edit those reasons in, folks.</sub>

Would also recommend importing `foo` objects into `__init__.py` by name rather than `from mypkg.foo import *` as you have more control about what goes into the `mypkg` namespace this way.

Comment: Thank you! Can I add docstring for methods of Logger class in __init__.py as well?

Comment: You might be better off including a high-level overview for `Logger` in `__init__.py` and putting the detail into `Logger`'s docstrings, as this is easier to maintain… but at the end of the day if you think it's useful to put that much detail there, you can!

Comment: Could you show me how to do this? declare Logger and its methods in __init__.py like this: ```def log_info(self, content):...```. And in another file I import Logger like this: ```from mypkg import Logger```. But when I call log_info, nothing gets printed.